# Perform PHP loops until end of array OR reaches certain number of iterations?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I wish to receive one array as input, filter values from it, and output as another array. The function should loop through up to `x` iterations.

For example, if I wanted to output **all** the values from the input, I would use:

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($data['type'] != 'some_value') {
        $formatted_array[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
}
return $formatted_array;
```

But if `$array` had a large index, the `$formatted_array` would be larger than I need. I tried using a `for` loop with multiple conditions, but it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop.

I'm not a developer by trade, so the logic is difficult to comprehend. I'm not getting errors, so it's hard to understand where exactly I'm going wrong.

How can I perform PHP loops until end of array or until the function reaches certain number of iterations?

Comment: Wouldn't array_filter fix this quite nice? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're on the right track - you can exit the `foreach` loop when you reach your count.  You use a `foreach` to iterate over the full array and if you never reach your stated maximum count, you will process the whole array.  But if you do reach the maximum, jump out of the loop.

```
$i = 0;
// Don't allow more than 5 if the array is bigger than 5
$maxiterations = 5;
foreach ($array as $data) {
  if ($i < $maxiterations) {
    if ($data['type'] != 'some_value') {
        $formatted_array[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
  }
  else  {  // Jump out of the loop if we hit the maximum
     break;
  }
}
return $formatted_array;
```

Comment: I like this, it fits in well with my existing code. Why would you choose this over meager's `while` loop solution?

Comment: @Joe If doing it from scratch, I probably would use a while loop, but this is just a tiny adaptation of the code you already have written.

Answer (score 18):

Use a `while` loop:

```
$i = 0;
$limit = 10;
$count = count($array);

while ($i < $limit && $i < $count) {
   $data = $array[$i];
   // your code here
   ++$i;
}
```

Comment: You can also do it with using for loop: for($i=0;$i < $limit && $i < $count;$i++)

Answer (score 2):

```
$max_iterations = 100;

for ($i=1;$i <=$max_iterations;$i++)
{
    if ($i <= count($array))
        //do what u need
    else
        break;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with a `break` statement?

User foreach loop and also maintain a counter variable every time you enter the code inside condition. If you reach the required number elements, that is counter reaches a certain value, break out of the loop.

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($data['type'] != 'some_value') {
        $formatted_array[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
        if($i>$maxAllowedElements) // here $i can serve as the counter and you can define //$maxAllowedElements to whatever value you like. 
         break;
    }
}
return $formatted_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            <?php foreach($usersinglevideodata1 as $userkey=>$uservalue){
                  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){if($uservalue['com_video'.$i.''] !=""){ if ($Count < 3){?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <iframe width="100%" height="120" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo youtube_id($uservalue['com_video'.$i.'']);?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <?php $Count++;}else{break;}}}?>
          <?php }}?>
```

**Note**: You're on the right track - you can exit the foreach loop when you reach your count. You use a foreach to iterate over the full array and if you never reach your stated maximum count, you will process the whole array. But if you do reach the maximum, jump out of the loop.

Comment: You're on the right track - you can exit the foreach loop when you reach your count. You use a foreach to iterate over the full array and if you never reach your stated maximum count, you will process the whole array. But if you do reach the maximum, jump out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $counter = 0;
  $new_array = array();
  while(count($new_array) <= $max_elements) {
    if($array[$counter]['type'] !== 'some_value') {
      $new_array[] = $array[$counter];
    }
  }
  return $new_array;
?>
```